# Sweet Alert is not working in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm using https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert package for Laravel 5. I'm using SweetAlerts in my controller but SweetAlerts is not working.

My Code:

```
\Alert::success('İşlem Başarılı!', 'Slider resmi ekleme işleminiz başarılı.');

return \Redirect::route('admin.sliders');
```

But if I'm using `return view('admin.sliders')` it's working. I need to be using Alert with Redirect::route.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Any advance on *"not working"*?

Comment: return view working but Redirect::route is not working.

Comment: That's not helpful. Give a [mcve].

Comment: What. Does. *"not working"*. Actually ***mean?!***

Comment: Updated. I can speak basic english. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work

In the controller add this line

```
use Alert;
```

After that add these lines of code inside the controller methods

```
Alert::success('İşlem Başarılı!', 'Slider resmi ekleme işleminiz başarılı.');
return redirect()->route('admin.sliders');
```

Check out the sweet alert documentation
https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert

Laravel HTTP Redirects documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects

I hope that helps !